# Can't play sound in Android Native Extension

Tags: android, eclipse, air-native-extension

Here's how I try it:

```
try {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context.getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.raw.mysound);
mediaPlayer.start();
} catch(Exception e) { Log.d("no sound",e.getMessage()); }
```

(mysound.mp3 is in res/raw/ folder in Eclipse project)

I pack the sound file to .ane in platform.xml like this:

```
<packagedResource> 
<packageName>com.myname.androidextension</packageName> 
<folderName>res</folderName> 
</packagedResource>
```

while having mysound.mp3 file in Android-ARM/res/raw/mysound.mp3

When I check the .ane file, the mp3 is inside.

But when I run the app on my phone, I dont hear the sound, instead I get a weird LogCat line:

```
no sound | File res/layout/main.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f030002
```

I don't understand it. Since it's a native extension ment for playing sounds, I don't need any layouts and there is no main.xml in my project.

Been googling like mad, but was unable to find anything I could use.

What does it mean and how can I make the sound play?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I have marked extension project as library and something changed, now LogCat shows this line instead of previous:

```
no sound | File res/raw/mysound.mp3 from drawable resource ID #0x7f040007
```

So no more mysterious main.xml and the id has changed. I checked the source of R.java and inside there was a line:

```
public static int mysound=0x7f030002;
```

So the ids in LogCat and in R.java don't match, but what does it mean?

Comment: I'm making an Air app and the sounds from as3 are terribly delayed on android devices (delay varies depending on device), so i'm trying to play them through the native extension. Been sitting two days now on this, but there is absolutely no info on the issue, it seems like no one else is developing Air apps or doesn't have any sound delay problems .. So is it just me, or ...

Comment: i do, mate. same problem here. it kinda sad that there are less resources found on flex mobile development especially on air native extension.